# Clones, hazardous environment, rebirth, human rights

Tags: story-identification, clones, genetic-engineering

A second-hand softback I read in the early 1980s - possibly written in the early to mid 1970s. Possibly the complete novel, or perhaps two or three stories in the one book, no more than that.

Artwork:

Pudgy, featureless, naked clones with hangdog and mindless expressions go about their work with a backdrop of small humans (scientist/technician types) looking on through a window.

Story:

There are people behind glass screens/windows supervising the work of the clones which are in a sealed environment. Some kind of hazardous work, not dangerous as far as I remember, just toxic to humans. It is also low-skilled but physically taxing, requiring great strength.

The clones themselves are big, 7 foot tall or more, muscular and globular humanoids all with identical features, but two sexes. They only last so long before they wear out, get arthritis and are unable to work - so they are recycled. The recycling process involves some sort of dissolution process and then regrowth of the clones from the solution - essentially they're made of the same stuff as before, but renewed. Then they're given basic training and put to work. They are mute and dealt with as property, not compassionately.

A scientist commissioned to increase their lifespan and productivity manages to find a way to make them remember one lifetime to the next, cutting down on training time each cycle.

A side effect of this memory retention is they start conjugating, enjoying the pleasure of the flesh. They also show each other care and in a simple way seem to start evolving a basic kind of culture.

The moral lesson, punch line if you will is the speculation that they could become reclassified as sentient, worthy of compassion. The upshot is that this would grant them all sorts of rights - this is not something the company at all welcomes as it will ultimately cost them money and potential bad publicity for human rights reasons. This gives them a reason to cover it up - the story ends there.